# Make custom variable in Django Context permanent

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm creating a website which has "categories" as a model in Django. To generate the sidebar, I iterate the categories and create a link for each one, which allows my to make it dinamic.

The issue is that with the current approach, I have to put `Categories.objects.all()` as a variable in the context on every view, and I'm sure this is not the correct approach. How should I do to set `categories` as a context variable for any future View?

Comment: Write custom context processor more help at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a context processor, like:

```
def categories(request):   #written in some file named processor.py
    return {'categories': Categories.objects.all()}
```

then add this context processor:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "myapp.processor.categories",         #you have added this line to settings
)
```

now you can use foo to any template as context variable.
http://catherinetenajeros.blogspot.com/2013/03/custom-template-context-processors.html

Answer (score 4):

An Approach would be writing a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors), you just have to define a function that returns a context like this:

```
def get_my_cool_context(request):
    return {}
```

and there you return all the variables you would like to use in all your views and then in all yours views you get your context like this

```
context = get_my_cool_context(request)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! While this is a good answer, It would be more useful if you could provide links to tutorials, or official documentation - It would help the asker,and also users in future !